# InAppBrowser how to disable scroll bouncing and enable horizontal scroll? Phonegap/Cordova3.1

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, inappbrowser

There is no option to tweak this, and obviously, we need to tweak CDVInAppBrowser.m (for iOS)

Someone can show me a guide?

Answer (score 0):

try to checkout my version:

https://github.com/apla/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

branch patch-1